# Change the user agent of Crosswalk 13+ as webview in Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I am trying to change the User Agent of Crosswalk used as webview for Cordova. I am currently using the plugin cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.

I am able to accomplish the customization of the user agent with vanilla Cordova with the following code:

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{   

    public WebSettings settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        settings = ((WebView) super.appView.getEngine().getView()).getSettings();
        String defaultUA = settings.getUserAgentString();
        String customUA = defaultUA+" OreeganoC1";
        settings.setUserAgentString(customUA);

        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

However, when i run the app with the Crosswalk plugin it crashes due to this piece of code. Everything works perfectly without Crosswalk.
I am using Cordova 5.2.0 and Crosswalk 13.

Any hints?

Comment: why are you changing user agent?

Comment: The app is fetching some pages from a remote website that changes its css  and js specifically for the app in order to give a better user experience. Therefore I need to identify when the request is coming from the app,
and checking the custom string in the UA is the simplest way i thought.

Comment: First of all if you are using Crosswalk, I think you should cast to XWalkView but not to standard android.webkit.WebView. And if you get XWalkView, you can use direct method [setUserAgent](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29) to set User-Agent. Something like this:
`walkView.setUserAgentString("NewAgent");`

Comment: How do you get the XWalkView in MainActivity, in order to change the user agent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the preferred method or not, but here's what I did (using Crosswalk 14+):

1. I added a custom preference to my config.xml:

   `<preference name="xwalkUserAgent" value="Custom UA" />`
2. In `Project/platforms/android/src/org/crosswalk/engine/XWalkWebViewEngine.java`, I added the following code inside the class:

   ```
   public static final String PREF_USER_AGENT = "xwalkUserAgent";
   protected CordovaPreferences preferences;
   ```

   In the constructor, I stored the preferences:

   ```
   public XWalkWebViewEngine(Context context, CordovaPreferences preferences) {
       this.preferences = preferences;
       ...
   }
   ```

   Finally, in the initWebViewSettings() method, I set the User Agent:

   ```
   private void initWebViewSettings() {
       webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
       String xwalkUserAgent = preferences.getString(PREF_USER_AGENT, "");
       webView.setUserAgentString(xwalkUserAgent);
   }
   ```

Now whenever I need to change the User Agent, I can do it from config.xml.